# Creating sequence in oracle database

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, rdbms

Is it possible to create a sequence name with non-ascii characters in Oracle when the name is longer than maxvalue of oracle? If yes, then how?

Comment: Show some examples telling what exactly you are trying to achieve with some sample data.

Comment: SEQ_Reg_رهسارثىحقخؤثسسAr1991

Comment: SEQ_Reg_رهسارثىحقخؤثسسAr1991 ...sequence name should be created in oracle dbms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in official docs, you can use non-ascii characters in identifiers by using quoted string (like this):

```
create sequence "SEQ_Reg_رهسارثىحقخؤثسسAr1991" start with 1;
```

Identifiers should be no more than 30 bytes long, but if you're using Oracle 12c and set COMPATIBLE initialization parameter to 12.2 or higher - you can use identifiers up to 128 bytes long.